# Batch conversions of lat, lon to US census tract?

Tags: us-census

I have 700,000 latitude/longitude pairs I need to convert to US Census tracts. Is there a free API that offers this in batches? So far the only option I have found is from the [FCC](https://www.fcc.gov/developers/census-block-conversions-api) and does not state a rate limit but has the form of a 1-1 call to return.

Comment: hi, could you go the other direction?  the census summary files (which are available in a few different ways, including one record per census tract) have INTPTLAT and INTPTLON on them already.  www.census.gov/prod/cen2010/doc/sf1.pdf#page=19

Answer (score 3):

Texas A&M's geocoder:
http://geoservices.tamu.edu/Services/Geocode/
Mapbox's google docs script to geocode google spreadsheets:
https://github.com/mapbox/geo-googledocs/
Smarty Street's geocoder if you're a non-profit:
https://smartystreets.com/features

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Census geocoder? https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/geocoder.html

The limit is 1,000 per batch, but that should be more doable for your project.

Comment: @gannawang I saw that but it appears to turn addresses into geo coordinates + census data. So to use it I'd have to first reverse geocode all my coordinates.

Comment: Can you first use the ggmap package in r to reverse geocode (you only get 2500 per day) then use the census api?